# how can I get the parameter passed from the OS to the application and then use it

Tags: java

I have developed my java application and deployed it.

I want it to detect when i double click a music file eg .mp4, .mp3 and others to open play.

I have already set it as my default but it just opens the app, it cannot pick the path of the file.

Colleagues, how do I get that file path and use it when it is called?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it a swing/fx application?

Comment: Hav you looked at the args in your main method?

Comment: The current behavior is the following : you double click on a .mp3, your application start, but is idle and do not load the .mp3 file. Correct? If yes, I would start by being sure it's not pass in the argv array in your main method.